# can I customize git push --mirror, or emulate with refspecs?

Tags: git

I understand `git push --mirror` deletes any refs and branches from the destination that are missing from the source repo (as well as forcing all other ref updates/creation).

I'd like a similar behaviour, but with a sub "namespace" in the destination.. it's for migrating an old repo hosting to a new one (involving a migration period where both repos may be updated): let's say I want mirroring to happen under refs/old/*.

I noticed `--mirror` doesn't allow refspecs, but this seem to do most of the job:

`git --git-dir oldrepo push newrepo +refs/*:refs/old/*`

So if a branch B is created in oldrepo, the above will push it as "refs/old/heads/B", and force non-FF updates.
However it's not deleting "refs/old/head/X" after X was deleted from oldrepo - I guess this is the missing part of the `--mirror` equivalence.

So is there any trick to achieve that? What's the reason for `--mirror` not taking refspec?